# Running gVim on a USB Drive

Tags: vim, gvim, usb-storage, vimrc, gvimrc

How could I run gVim on a USB drive (I can't install software on the computer) preferably I'd like to load it on the USB drive with a mac (so I can't install an exe - but I *could* use a pc) and also how could I load my `.vimrc` file on drive and gVim use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear what OS this is for.  If it's for Windows you should be able to copy the entire install directory from a machine you *can* install to—or from a machine that already has it installed—onto the USB drive and run it from there.  Vim will look for a vimrc file in the same directory as the Vim executable.

See "`:help $VIM`" and "`:help vimrc`".